# ajax load an another html page/div with lightbox effect

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to load another html page in the same folder with lightbox effect, can someone help me out where to find the resource to learn this method? I try jquery .load(), but it's not quite what i'm looking for. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is, inside your lightbox pop-up, include an iframe that points to your desired html page.

Going into any further detail would require knowing what lightbox plugin you are using (and quite frankly any decent plugin should have loads of iframe implementation examples on their docs page anyways).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try jQuery-UI, and use jQuery-Dialog.
An example here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog